# 3-connectedness Expansion Lemma

Tags: graph-theory, alternative-proof

The question is as follows:

> Prove that applying the expansion operation* to a 3-connected graph yields a 3-connected graph.

*The expansion operation is as follows: you take two edges of a graph G, replace them by paths of length 2 through new vertices, and add an edge joining the two new vertices - the new graph is G'. (some research showed it's also called "BG-operation").

My method of solution was:

If I manage to show that G'-v for every $v\in V(G')$ is 2-connected, then G' is 3-connected. I split the cases for $v\in V(G)$, and $v \in (s,t)$ (where s,t are the two new vertices from the expansion). I then show that G'-v on both cases have ear-decomposition, based on ear-decomposition from G-v in the first case, and G-xy (where xy is the edge divided by s) in the second case.

My question is:

> Are there any other methods, **not** using ear-decomposition to prove it?

Comment: Maybe it's too naive, but can't you use Menger's theorem ?  Say that vertices $a,b$ have 3 disjoint paths in $G$, they still do in $G'$.  Now, if you added a vertex $x$ in $G'$ between say $a$ and $c$, then $x$ should have 3 disjoint paths to $b$ - we just use that same paths from $a$ to $b$.  It seems possible to fill in the details from that.

Comment: Sounds wonderful actually. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: Ah but actually something is not working in that idea.  Such an $x$ cannot use $a$ or $c$ in more than one path.  That means that to find a third path, we need to use a newly created neighbor of $x$.